# ionic angular ngrx how to access a store

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngrx

i am working on an ionic angular cordova app. I am trying to print my state, for example, all the objects in the state. However it cannot find the objects i putted inside.

model

```
export interface Room {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

action

```
export class AddRoom implements Action {
    readonly type = ADD_ROOM;

    constructor(public payload: Room){}
}
```

reducer

```
const initialState: Room = {
    id: 111,
    name: 'null'
}

export function reducer(state: Room[] = [initialState], action: RoomActions.Actions ){
    switch (action.type) {
        case RoomActions.ADD_ROOM:
            return [...state];
        case RoomActions.REMOVE_ROOM:
            state.splice(action.payload, 1);
            return state;
            default:
                return state;
    }
}
```

code

```
rooms2: any;


constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
      this.rooms2 = this.store.select('room');
      }
console.log(this.rooms2);
```

but in the console, i can only see a store object in which i cannot find any data i am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NgRx Store is reactive.

`this.rooms2 = this.store.select('room');` returns an Observable, and this is probably what you're seeing.

Try the following:

```
this.rooms2.subscribe(rooms => console.log(rooms))
```